# Select Serializer for field in Django Serializer class

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, serialization

i have Model where i can have owner is user or client

```
@property
    def owner(self):
        return self.created_by_user or self.created_by_client
```

and have serializer where i need this field

```
class MessageSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
owner = (can be user or client) i take it from @property in model
```

I have 2 serializer UserSerializer and ClientSerializer i want write for owner something like this

```
owner = UserSerializer if insstance(User, value) or ClientSerializer if insstance(Client, value)
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this using DRF's [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) like:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_owner(self, instance):
        value = instance.field # replace the field name
        if instance.created_by_user:
            return UserCreatedSerializer(value).data
        elif instance.created_by_client:
            return ClientCreatedSerializer(value).data
```

I'm sorry if I incorrectly used property and serializer names, but I think you will get the basic idea: since owner is the property, DRF serializer can't serialize property directly so you have to use SerializerMethodField and serialize your owner based on the test logic in the method

hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thx its help me. I change  value = instance.field to  value = instance.owner.